# How to pass several parameters via pathParam() [REST-ASSURED, API]

Tags: api, rest-assured

**How do I pass several parameters via pathParam() in the following rest-assured POST request?**

I tried this:

```
enter code here

createBaseRequest(userRequestSpecification)
                .when()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .pathParam("permalink", requestExpertTeam.getPermalink())
                .pathParam("id", parseInt(getLoggedUserId(userRequestSpecification)))
                .put(ENDPOINT_ADD_USER_TO_EXPERT_TEAM)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .as(UserDTO.class);
```

But the IntelliJ starts yelling:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path parameters were not correctly defined. Redundant path parameters are: id=252.

When I change 'pathParam' in [pathParam("id", parseInt(getLoggedUserId(userRequestSpecification)))] to 'queryParam' IntelliJ starts yelling that  it expects two params but got only one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add more detail about `ENDPOINT_ADD_USER_TO_EXPERT_TEAM`? I want to see the URL path (you can change domain to `localhost` or anything)

Comment: Hello Lucas, thank You for your reply, actually ENDPOINT_ADD_USER_TO_EXPERT_TEAM stands for  "/api/teams/{permalink}/add-user/{user_id}".

Comment: This one is not something that works via local host :)

Comment: the problem is so clear. No `id` in pathParam, it is `user_id` . Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the placeholder in URL for pathParam `id`. If RA see that mismatch between `pathParam` and `URL`, they will fire an error.

```
.pathParam("permalink", "abc")
.pathParam("id", 1)

http://localhost:8080/{permalink}/{id}
```